# OLE-Server busy when page is refreshed: AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, access-violation, ole, managed

I have a managed 32-bit C++ OLE-Server (viewer application) installed on the user's machine and registered as a OLE-Server for a particular extension; the web page "serves out" a file with this extension inside a frame.

While the OLE-Server is busy processing the file in the web page (Win7-IE9), if the page is refreshed by the user, Windows pops up a "not working" box and the program gets a AccessViolationException entry in the Event Log.

I do have a try-catch(Exception ^pe) around the main code that is busy during that time, but it doesn't seem to catch the exception.

Is there any way of handling this situation?

Comment: I would assume that C++/CLI only catches .NET exceptions in a `catch(Exc^ pe)`, no? If it's an actual AV (nullptr access or something), you might get lucky with `__try / __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) { ... }`. Also check the `/EH` switch (`/EHa`vs. `/EHsc`) for the C++ `catch(...)` construct.

Comment: @MartinBa hadn't thought of that! I have some problems with my Visual Studio at home, will try this out and get back to you -- thanks!